# BufferedReader from only some bytes of InputStream

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, inputstream

I have an InputStream that I would like to read in concurrently. As such I do some logic to figure out for each thread what the

```
long start = // byte number for thread to start working on
long end = // byte number for thread to end working on
```

And then I want some way to do a computation starting on byte number start and ending on byte number end. I know I can use InputStream.skip(start) for the first part, but how do I stop a process after byte end?

```
public void logic(long start, long end) {
   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
   is.skip(start);
   doComputation(is);
   // stop at is.byteNumber == end - don't know how to do this
   is.close();
}
```

Then...

```
    public void doComputation(is) {
       try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) { 
           //do things line by line
       }
    }
```

Any and all help would be appreciate.

Comment: Reading from an InputStream gives you the number of bytes read, you'll have to figure out the BufferedReader yourself.

Comment: Use a `FileChannel` that allows you to [truly read a part from a file concurrently](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read-java.nio.ByteBuffer-long-). Then use the desired charset to [`decode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#decode-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) the buffer into a string. Of course, this does not harmonize with “do things line by line” as there is no guaranty that an arbitrary file byte position is a line break.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
Reads characters into a portion of an array.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html